# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[(-31)^{1/(2n+1)}+(-93)^{1/(2n+3)}-(-75)^{1/(2n+5)}\right]^{n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to evaluate this limit?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[(-31)^{1/(2n+1)}+(-93)^{1/(2n+3)}-(-75)^{1/(2n+5)}\right]^{n}$$

I know that the above limit is of the form of $1^{\infty}$. Also I know the formula for solving limits of the form of $1^{\infty}$. The formula is $$e^{\lim_{x\to \infty}[g(x)×(f(x)-1)]}$$ × $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$$; where $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$$ = 1 and$$\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$$ = $\infty$. The function is of the form of $F(x)$ = $f(x)^{g(x)}$. But how to solve this question? Please help me out. I can't solve this question also after applying the concept of solving the limits of the form of $1^{\infty}$.

Comment: Please edit your question. This is hard to read as it it.

Comment: Already edited@JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: The base tends to $-1-1+1=-1$ so the limit won't exist.

Comment: Actually at n$\to \infty$ the limit will be of the form of $1^{\infty}$.@ParamanandSingh

Comment: @Prateep No. For $a<0$, you have that $a^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}\to -1$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Yes you are correct @Mr.GandalfSauron. But $$\lim_{n\to \infty} a^{1/(2n+1)}$$ will tend to 1. If you don't believe me then you can check the same in desmos and Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Because as far as I know in limits we just find the limiting value and for that reason only while finding the limiting value we put n=$\infty$.

Comment: @Prateep It's not a matter of "belief". It's an establishable fact which does not need to rely on desmos or wolframalpha. For $a>0$ , you have $a^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}\to 1$. But for $a<0$, you have $a^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}\to -1$. And as far as your intuitive notion for limits goes, NO it is not at all the same as putting $n=\infty$. I understand that at the high school level, one cannot go into the $\epsilon-\delta$ and rigourous analytical notions but rather one hopes that after seeing sufficiently many examples that one developes an intuition for it.

Answer (score 1):

As Paramanand Singh pointed out, the OP’s limit does not exist, but we could calculate the following limit :

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[31^{1/(2n+1)}+(-93)^{1/(2n+3)}-(-75)^{1/(2n+5)}\right]^n$

which is equal to

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[31^{\frac1{2n+1}}+75^{\frac1{2n+5}}-93^{\frac1{2n+3}}\right]^n\,.$

Or rather, we could calculate the limit

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[a^{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}+b^{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}-c^{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}\right]^n$

where $\,a,b,c,\lambda,\alpha,\beta,\,\gamma\in\Bbb R\,,$ $\,a,b,c>0\,$ and $\,\lambda\neq0\,.$

Since the previous limit is of the form $\,1^\infty,\,$ we can apply the formula

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[f(n)\right]^{g(n)}=e^{\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(n)\left[f(n)-1\right]}\,.$

Consequently,

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[a^{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}+b^{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}-c^{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}\right]^n\!=e^{\,\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n\big[a^{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}+b^{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}-c^{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}-1\big]}\,.$

Moreover,

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n\!\left[a^{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}+b^{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}-c^{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}-1\right]=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\!\left[\left(a^{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}-1\right)+\left(b^{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}-1\right)-\left(c^{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}-1\right)\right]$

and, by applying the notable limit $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{a^x-1}x=\ln a\;\,,$
we get that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(a^{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}-1\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac n{\lambda n+\alpha}\left(\!\dfrac{a^{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}-1}{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}\!\right)=\dfrac1\lambda\ln a\;\;,$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(b^{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}-1\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac n{\lambda n+\beta}\left(\!\dfrac{b^{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}-1}{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}\!\right)=\dfrac1\lambda\ln b\;\;,$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(c^{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}-1\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac n{\lambda n+\gamma}\left(\!\dfrac{c^{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}-1}{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}\!\right)=\dfrac1\lambda\ln c\;.$

Hence ,

$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n\!\left[a^{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}+b^{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}-c^{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}-1\right]&=\dfrac1\lambda\big(\ln a+\ln b-\ln c\big)=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1\lambda\ln\!\left(\!\dfrac{ab}c\right)\end{align}$

and $\;\;\color{blue}{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[a^{\frac1{\lambda n+\alpha}}+b^{\frac1{\lambda n+\beta}}-c^{\frac1{\lambda n+\gamma}}\right]^n\!=\left(\!\dfrac{ab}c\right)^{\!\frac1\lambda}}\,.$

Therefore ,

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[31^{1/(2n+1)}+(-93)^{1/(2n+3)}-(-75)^{1/(2n+5)}\right]^n=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[31^{\frac1{2n+1}}+75^{\frac1{2n+5}}-93^{\frac1{2n+3}}\right]^n=$

$=\left(\!\dfrac{31\!\cdot\!75}{93}\right)^{\!\frac12}=5\,.$